# TinyMCE Plugin Parameter

Tags: tinymce, editor, wp-editor, plugin-tinymce

Can anyone tell me if there is anywhere I can find out what each of these TinyMCE plugins are for?

```
$in['plugins']='inlinepopups,tabfocus,paste,media,fullscreen,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs,wpfullscreen';
```

I'm wondering because if I remove the `wordpress` one that the editor will stop stripping out my `<p>` tags, but I also lose all my spacing in the `html` view of the editor as well.

Comment: TinyMCE is a separate project that WordPress uses.  It's sometimes difficult to determine if the question is best asked here, or is 'off topic.'  Depends on the degree of integration, I suppose.  This one is more on the 'off topic' side, as you're not asking how to integrate.  You can find each plugin easily by searching TinyMCE plugin [name] - for example: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/tab_focus.php

Comment: These plugins are WordPress specific, and so the question is absolutely on topic here.

Comment: @toscho - You're half right.  As for the rest, I took it as a challenge _(and penance for jumping the gun with my comment)_ to figure out the rest.

Comment: btw - if you're primarily interested in preventing wp from stripping out certain tags, there filters for that.  See: http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/allow-more-html-tags-in-the-editor/ for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few you listed are not WordPress specific, and information about them can be found as follows:

1. [**inlinepopups**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3ainlinepopups)
2. [**tabfocus**](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/tab_focus.php)
3. [**paste**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste)
4. [**media**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3amedia)
5. [**fullscreen**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3afullscreen)

[As for the WordPress specific plugins, their source code is here (trac)](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins?rev=21592&order=name).  There are no comments, but here's my take based on a very cursory read through:

1. **wordpress:** seems to setup the editor with default buttons, classes, size, etc
2. **wpeditimage:** seems to add the insert media dialog
3. **wpgallery:** launches tb_show("",tinymce.documentBaseURL+"**/media-upload.php**?post_id="+f+"&tab=gallery&TB_iframe=true&width="+d+"&height="+g) which adds the gallery dialog
4. **wplink:** seems to add the insert link dialog
5. **wpdialogs:** adds tinyMCEPopup js function, probably used by the other dialogs
6. **wpfullscreen:** puts the editor in wordpress 'distraction free' full screen mode.  Not sure why this one and the standard fullscreen plugin both exist.

Comment: The look of the WP-Fullscreenmode (aka dfw; distraction free writing) is different from the default fullscreen plugin. The dfw also need specific DOM elements and css. If you use a custom editor and do not provide these DOM elements and css, the default fullscrenn plugin works as a fallback.